# Vt-d enabling blurs the screen

Tags: virtualization

I enabled Vt-d on my core 2 duo machine, but this has a side effect of blurring my screen and windows 50% of the time. I'm attaching a screenshot to give some idea. Does anybody know what the problem might be. And should I report this as a but to microsoft and how?
Please note that the problem is on the host desktop, and not the guest. I haven't even opened my Virtualization app, let alone start a VM.

[image: Blurred screen and window]

Comment: Any suggestions, anyone? Please. I really need to get this problem solved. As time passes, its almost all the time and the complete screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned Aero off and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To me that looks like corruption in the display memory (though without seeing it live I can't be 100% certain).

Does the problem persist if you reduce the resolution of the screen?

To report the problem to Microsoft go to http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: Yes, changing resolution doesn't help. Moreover, this occurs both when I'm only using my laptop's LCD display and also when I attach an extra CRT monitor, in which case it occurs on both screens. Also the blurs actually move. e.g. If there is a blur on a card in a game, it will carry when I move the card. This occurs only when Vt-d is enabled, otherwise all is well.